# jQuery autocomplete textbox ID

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

Just having a mess around with jQuery. Very new to this.
Have had a search for my issue with no luck.

I currently have 2 columns of text boxes, ID's being code + count + & description + count +.
On each of the code boxes i have autocomplete which then adds the label of that value to the description box.

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P26N8.png

How do i get the id of the text box so i can use that number to send the description to that text box.

would like something like:

```
var id = currenttextboxid(number only)

$( "#description" + id + "" ).val(ui.item.label);
```

Appreciate your help people :)

Sorry if i have worded that terribly.

Comment: you want to get the id only?

Comment: Yeah, just so i can move a second value to the other box (that has the same id number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

html

```
<input type="text" id="descroption1"/>
```

script

```
$("input").click(function(){
alert((this.id).replace("descroption",""));

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EbU6a/117/)

```
  $("input").each(function(){
   alert((this.id).replace("descroption",""));

});
```

Comment: This has done it.
this.id = this.id.replace("code","");
        $( "#description" + this.id + "" ).val(ui.item.label);